# HTML PHP Adding quantity and Price to my Menu items

Tags: php, html, forms

i am trying to create a restaurant order summary where the customer can select his order via CheckBox and quantity and get the sum of prices at the End.
When choosing chicken its working perfectly ex: You have selected 3 chicken  and returns correct price, but when i check another and choose other quantity it is either 
giving 0 selection or giving 1 quantity even if i put 5 for example.
Only chicken is working others not.

View my code and screen shot of example with output.
[image: Test 2 should give: you have selected 2 Meat Total 6]

Here is my code:

```
<body>
<h3>Select what you want to eat</h3>

<form action="PlaceOrder.php" method="get"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="choice[]" value="1"/>Chicken,Price:8
<input name="quantity[]" type="text" /><br />

<input type="checkbox" name="choice[]" value="2"/>Meat,Price:3
<input name="quantity[]" type="text" /><br />

<input type="checkbox" name="choice[]" value="3"/>Souvlaki,Price:2.50
<input name="quantity[]" type="text" /><br />

<input type="checkbox" name="choice[]" value="4"/>Pizza,Price:12
<input name="quantity[]" type="text" /><br />

<input type="submit" value="Order"/>
</form>
```

and php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["choice"])){
$food=$_GET["choice"];
$quantity=$_GET["quantity"];
$c = count($food);
$price = 0.0;


for ($i=0; $i<$c ; $i++){
    if ($food[$i] == 1){
        $price = $price + 8 * $quantity[$i];
//here it's not working with quantity
        echo "You have selected " .$quantity[$i]." Chicken <br>";
    }

    if ($food[$i] == 2){
        $price = $price + 3 * $quantity[$i];
        echo "You have selected" .$quantity[$i]." Meat <br>";
    }

    if ($food[$i] == 3){
        $price = $price + 2.5 * $quantity[$i];
        echo "You have selected " .$quantity[$i]."Souvlaki <br>";
    }

    if ($food[$i] == 4){
        $price = $price + 12 * $quantity[$i];
        echo "You have selected" .$quantity[$i]." Pizza <br>";
    }       
   }

  echo "Total: ".$price . "<br>";
}
else {
echo "Please select something!";
}


?>




</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the checkboxes that are not checked don't get send to PHP, so your code wont work the way you have it there. You need to include more information about each item in your form so it's easier to work with the data on the PHP side, plus this way you don't have to repeat yourself when it comes to showing the item names. try something like this:

```
<?php
$total = 0;
$items = [];
$info  = 'Select something to order.';

// form submitted
if( !empty( $_POST['choice'] ) && is_array( $_POST['choice'] ) )
{
    // loop all item choices
    foreach( $_POST['choice'] as $item )
    {
        // filter item info
        $name     = trim( $item['name'] );
        $price    = floatval( $item['price'] );
        $quantity = intval( $item['quantity'] );

        // only add if item was checked and quantity is more than 0
        if( isset( $item['checked'] ) && $quantity > 0 )
        {
            $items[] = $quantity .' '. $name;
            $total  += $price * $quantity;
        }
    }
    // update info if items were selected
    if( count( $items ) )
    {
        $info = 'You selected ('.implode( ', ', $items ).'), total: '.$total;
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Order Form</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>

    <form id="order-form" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
        <div class="form-item">
            <input type="checkbox" name="choice[0][checked]" />
            <span>Chicken, Price: 8</span>
            <input type="number" name="choice[0][quantity]" value="1" />
            <input type="hidden" name="choice[0][price]" value="8" />
            <input type="hidden" name="choice[0][name]" value="Chicken" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-item">
            <input type="checkbox" name="choice[1][checked]" />
            <span>Meat, Price: 3</span>
            <input type="number" name="choice[1][quantity]" value="1" />
            <input type="hidden" name="choice[1][price]" value="3" />
            <input type="hidden" name="choice[1][name]" value="Meat" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-item">
            <input type="checkbox" name="choice[2][checked]" />
            <span>Souvlaki, Price: 2.50</span>
            <input type="number" name="choice[2][quantity]" value="1" />
            <input type="hidden" name="choice[2][price]" value="2.50" />
            <input type="hidden" name="choice[2][name]" value="Souvlaki" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-item">
            <input type="checkbox" name="choice[3][checked]" />
            <span>Pizza, Price: 12</span>
            <input type="number" name="choice[3][quantity]" value="1" />
            <input type="hidden" name="choice[3][price]" value="12" />
            <input type="hidden" name="choice[3][name]" value="Pizza" />
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Order"/>
    </form>

    <hr />
    <p><?= $info ?></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
$price = $price + 3 * $quantity[$i];
```

It is

```
$price = $price + 8 * $quantity[$food[$i]-1];
```

BTW, you need to change the value in the 'food' to number, it is a string when you get it from the form.

```
if(isset($_GET["choice"])){
$food=$_GET["choice"];
$quantity=$_GET["quantity"];
// begin type-cast
// without the '&',this code won't modify a array element directly
// We could iterate the array normally(without '&') and push the value to a new array,
// But that may change the order of the $quantity, I am not sure, so I'd better reference the element directly.   
foreach ($food as &$value) {
//(int) change it to a number.
    $value = (int)$value;
}
foreach ($quantity as &$value) {
    $value = (int)$value;
}
// type-cast done
$c = count($food);
$price = 0.0;


for ($i=0; $i<$c ; $i++){
if ($food[$i] == 1){
    $price = $price + 8 * $quantity[$food[$i]-1];
    echo "You have selected " .$quantity[$food[$i]-1]." Chicken <br>";
}

if ($food[$i] == 2){
    $price = $price + 3 * $quantity[$food[$i]-1];
    echo "You have selected " .$quantity[$food[$i]-1]." Meat <br>";
}

if ($food[$i] == 3){
    $price = $price + 2.5 * $quantity[$food[$i]-1];
    echo "You have selected " .$quantity[$food[$i]-1]." Souvlaki <br>";
}

if ($food[$i] == 4){
    $price = $price + 12 * $quantity[$food[$i]-1];
    echo "You have selected " .$quantity[$food[$i]-1]." Pizza <br>";
}       
}

  echo "Total: ".$price . "<br>";
}
else {
echo "Please select something!";
}


?>
```

HTML
    // You have a typo here
    
    Chicken,Price:8

```
<input type="checkbox" name="choice[]" value="2"/>Meat,Price:3
<input name="quantity[]" type="text" /><br />

<input type="checkbox" name="choice[]" value="3"/>Souvlaki,Price:2.50
<input name="quantity[]" type="text" /><br />

<input type="checkbox" name="choice[]" value="4"/>Pizza,Price:12
<input name="quantity[]" type="text" /><br />

<input type="submit" value="Order"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The length of food array and quantity array are not always the same.

Example:

food array (var_dump)

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(1) "3" }
```

quantity array also has empty values(var_dump)

```
array(4) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(1) "4" [2]=> string(1) "5" [3]=> string(0) "" }
```

This worked for me:

```
if ($food[$i] == 1){
    $price = $price + 8 * $quantity[0];
    echo "You have selected " .$quantity[0]." Chicken <br>";
    continue;
}

if ($food[$i] == 2){
    $price = $price + 3 * $quantity[1];
    echo "You have selected" .$quantity[1]." Meat <br>";
}

if ($food[$i] == 3){
    $price = $price + 2.5 * $quantity[2];
    echo "You have selected " .$quantity[2]."Souvlaki <br>";
}

if ($food[$i] == 4){
    $price = $price + 12 * $quantity[3];
    echo "You have selected" .$quantity[3]." Pizza <br>";
}
```

Hope it works for you, correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: can you please be more specific and give more explanation about the example ? with comments if possible. Thank you.

Comment: Check the length of array of food and quantity array using var dump in your error case